# Mat is not being destroyed properly

Tags: c#, emgucv

In my software, written in C#, I implemented an image class for internal purposes. Inside that class im am holding a `Mat` from emgu CV.

```
class MyOwnImage : IDisposable
{
    private Mat mat;

    public MyOwnImage( Mat mat ) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        mat.Dispose();
    }
    //...
}
```

Now, I discovered, that my memory usage is growing and growing regardless if I call `Dispose()` or not on the `Image` objects. I took a closer look at the `Mat` class and recognized that it has unmaneged memory inside in form of a `IntPtr`. So, i made a try, if manually freeing the pointer makes a difference:

```
class MyOwnImage : IDisposable
{
    private Mat mat;

    public MyOwnImage( Mat mat ) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal( mat.DataPointer ); // data pointer is the IntPtr
        mat.Dispose();
    }
    //...
}
```

I was a bit surprised, but it solved the issue of the overflowing memory. So, I assumed that I had to destroy the data inside the `Mat` object manually. Afterwards, I tried to make this more stable by adding a destructor, if someone forgets to manually `Dispose()` the image.

```
class MyOwnImage : IDisposable
{
    private Mat mat;

    public MyOwnImage( Mat mat ) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }

    ~MyOwnImage() {
        destroy();
    }

    private void destroy() {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal( mat.DataPointer ); // data pointer is the IntPtr
        mat.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        destroy();
    }
    //...
}
```

Sadly, this turned into a new problem: From time to time, when the desctructor is called, the `Mat` object seems to be already destroyed. Followingly, an `AccessViolationExcetion` is thrown on the line calling `FreeHGlobal(...)`. Now, I made another test and removed the `destroy()` call inside the `Dispose()` function.

```
class MyOwnImage : IDisposable
{
    private Mat mat;

    public MyOwnImage( Mat mat ) {
        this.mat = mat;
    }

    ~MyOwnImage() {
        destroy();
    }

    private void destroy() {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal( mat.DataPointer ); // data pointer is the IntPtr
        mat.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        //destroy();
    }
    //...
}
```

Strangely, this did not change anything about the fact, that `mat` inside `MyOwnImage` seems already be gone when the destructor `~MyOwnImage` is called.

Finally, I am wondering about several things:

1. Is it possible that if I manually call `Dispose()`, the destructor will be called as well later on?
2. Is it possible that the internal objects of `MyOwnImage` are destroyed before the destructor of this class is called?
3. If there is an OpenCV expert: Is it possible that disposing the mat does not free the data inside? If yes, is it a bug or is there a reason for this?

Comment: The ownership model here is flawed.  You have a class that takes a `Mat` in its constructor that was created elsewhere but then assumes responsibility for freeing it - this is prone to errors.  Whatever creates the `Mat` should be responsible for making sure it is disposed.  Here you don't have that guarantee.  Where does the `Mat` get created?  Consider cloning the `Mat` in the constructor instead - that creates a new instance which your class then can take responsibility for.  It still doesn't solve the problem of what to do with the `Mat` you`re creating outside this class.

Comment: It seems you may be 're inventing' the [disposable pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implement-the-dispose-pattern) (for unmanaged resources). The pattern includes the case where Dispose has been called more than once, or not at all and clean up is left to the finalizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was pointed out by J... in the comments.

The ownership model was violated. As he suggested, I cloned the `Mat` object inside MyOwnImage and now it is working.

```
class MyOwnImage : IDisposable
{
    private Mat mat;

    public MyOwnImage( Mat passedMat ) {
        var copy = new Mat();
        passedMat.CopyTo( copy );
        mat = copy;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        mat.Dispose();
    }
    //...
}
```